# WiX installer fails with error code 2819

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5

I am trying to create an installer using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) which doesn't show the license agreement at the start. But I get the error as below.

[image: Screenshot]

This is the full Product.wxs file I have at the moment. It compiles and builds OK. Why am I getting an error like this? Is my Fragment section in the right place? I have removed the Publish elements pertaining to license and modified the welcome dialog's next button to show the install directory dialog instead of license agreement. This is as mentioned in the help chm file. What am I missing then?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="077765d1-236d-4299-b751-f921828f2ac8"
           Name="Wix Setup Example"
           Language="1033"
           Version="1.0.0.0"
           Manufacturer="NBL" UpgradeCode="1b0f72a7-8e17-4897-9f96-66509cc39573">

        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes"  />

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder"  >
                <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="My Application Folder">
                    <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="MY-GUID-HERE">
                        <File Id="WindowsFormsApp.exe"
                            Source="../WindowsFormsApp/bin/Debug/WindowsFormsApp.exe">
                        </File>
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixSetupProject" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
        </Feature>

        <UI Id="WixUI_Advanced">
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

            <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
            <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Advanced" />

            <DialogRef Id="BrowseDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="DiskCostDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
            <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
            <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
            <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

            <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="3">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="4"><![CDATA[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="1">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="4">WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

            <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
        </UI>
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
    </Product>
    <Fragment>
        <Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="My Application Folder" />
        <Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerMachineFolder" />

        <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerUser" Value="1" Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerMachine" Value="1" Overridable="yes" />

        <PropertyRef Id="ApplicationFolderName" />
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The edited version of the WiX file that gives no error. This version however skips the install feature and browse for the file dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="077765d1-236d-4299-b751-f921828f2ac8"
           Name="Wix Setup Example"
           Language="1033"
           Version="1.0.0.0"
           Manufacturer="NBL" UpgradeCode="1b0f72a7-8e17-4897-9f96-66599gg39573">

        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes"  />

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="My Application Folder">
                    <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="17e13748-8d44-47f6-b020-66d29f8a84fe">
                        <File Id="WindowsFormsApp.exe"
                            Source="../WindowsFormsApp/bin/Debug/WindowsFormsApp.exe">
                        </File>
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixSetupProject" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
        </Feature>

        <UI Id="WixUI_Advanced">
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

            <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
            <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Advanced" />
            <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" />

            <DialogRef Id="BrowseDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="DiskCostDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
            <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
            <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
            <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

            <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="3">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="4"><![CDATA[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="1">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="BrowseDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="4">WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

            <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
        </UI>
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="My Application Folder" />
        <Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerMachineFolder" />

        <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerUser" Value="1" Overridable="yes" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerMachine" Value="1" Overridable="yes" />

        <PropertyRef Id="ApplicationFolderName" />
        <UI >
            <Dialog Id="CustomBrowseDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.BrowseDlg_Title)">
                <Control Id="PathEdit" Type="PathEdit" X="25" Y="202" Width="320" Height="18" Property="_BrowseProperty" Indirect="yes" />
                <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="240" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIOK)">
                    <Publish Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[_BrowseProperty]">1</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="Reset" Value="0">1</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="ComboLabel" Type="Text" X="25" Y="58" Width="44" Height="10" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgComboLabel)" />
                <Control Id="DirectoryCombo" Type="DirectoryCombo" X="70" Y="55" Width="220" Height="80" Property="_BrowseProperty" Indirect="yes" Fixed="yes" Remote="yes">
                    <Subscribe Event="IgnoreChange" Attribute="IgnoreChange" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="WixUI_Bmp_Up" Type="PushButton" X="298" Y="55" Width="19" Height="19" ToolTip="!(loc.BrowseDlgWixUI_Bmp_UpTooltip)" Icon="yes" FixedSize="yes" IconSize="16" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgWixUI_Bmp_Up)">
                    <Publish Event="DirectoryListUp" Value="0">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="NewFolder" Type="PushButton" X="325" Y="55" Width="19" Height="19" ToolTip="!(loc.BrowseDlgNewFolderTooltip)" Icon="yes" FixedSize="yes" IconSize="16" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgNewFolder)">
                    <Publish Event="DirectoryListNew" Value="0">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="DirectoryList" Type="DirectoryList" X="25" Y="83" Width="320" Height="98" Property="_BrowseProperty" Sunken="yes" Indirect="yes" TabSkip="no" />
                <Control Id="PathLabel" Type="Text" X="25" Y="190" Width="320" Height="10" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgPathLabel)" />
                <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgBannerBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgDescription)" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.BrowseDlgTitle)" />
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Removing that gets the following error in the MSI logs:

```
DEBUG: Error 2819:  Control Folder on dialog InstallDirDlg needs a property linked to it
```

Basically this means that the "browse for folder" control isn't linked up to an actual property value. You've used the value `INSTALLLOCATION` for the application folder - which in turn means you'll need to add the following value to link the dialog:

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLLOCATION" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I had a valid guid in the script. Just put "MY-GUID-HERE" for this post. :) Anyways, I updated the script with the property you specified and made a few changes. Now this takes away the error and I am able to skip the license agreement part. But it doesnt prompt me for the browze folder and install feature dialog anymore. Could you please check my file and see what I could be missing? Thanks.

Comment: "Removing that gets...."? Removing what? What would I have to remove?

Answer (score 7):

My experience is: you should add Property attribute in Control tag. Like:

```
<Control Id="NameEdit" Type="Edit"
         X="45" Y="85" Width="220" Height="18"
         Property="USERNAME" Text="{80}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Error code 2819 means "Control [3] on dialog [2] needs a property linked to it" (taken from [Windows Installer Error Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). If you extract the MSI traces (add /l*v  to the command line) you'll be able to see what [3] and [2] stand for, and continue debugging from there.

Comment: like I wrote in the answer add /l*v to the msiexec command line

Comment: @user20358 Run installation with `msiexec /i product.msi /l*vx install.log`.